# Wlp2s0 state DOWN, mode Dormant

Tags: networking, network-manager

Occasionally I don't get access to the internet for no apparent reason. I get the error message `activation of the network failed`. Looking deeper into the problem I noticed that my wlp2s0 state is DOWN and mode Dormant (not sure if the problem because of the mode). Cannot put it back up using `ip link set wlp2s0 up`.

Activation of network connection failed:

```
root@pirate-pc:~# cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
network:
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager
ethernets:
wlp2s0:
dhcp4: yes
optional: true
```

Results of `sudo netplan apply` :

> **(generate:4666): WARNING **: 13:02:55.836: Permissions for /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all .yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.
>
> **(process:4664): WARNING **: 13:02:56.394: Permissions for /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all. yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.
>
> ** (process:4664): WARNING **: 13:02:56.589: Permissions for /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all. yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.
>
> ** (process:4664): WARNING **: 13:02:56.589: Permissions for /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all. yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.

Results of `ip link` :

```
1: Lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default ql en 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 
3: virbre: <NO-CARRIER, BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000   
    link/ether 52:54:00:31:37:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlp2se: <NO-CARRIER, BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:e8:68: d0:35:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: "Permissions for /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all. yaml are too open." Please do: `sudo chmod 0600 /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` Then try: `sudo netplan generate` and: `sudo netplan apply` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.